# JavaScript Firebase maintain offline database for login using realtime database

Tags: javascript, cordova, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, phonegap-plugins

I am working on app which have two kind of login.

Means I need to login offline and online both.

For online I will use the web service. But for offline I want to maintain `Javascript Firebase Realtime Database`.

I have downloaded required js files to my resources.

And also I have initialize the Firebase.

**I want to sync the database with my app with some events. But how to sync that is not clear for me.**

```
<script src="js/firebase.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.5.2/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="js/firebase-database.js"></script>

<script>
  // Initialize Firebase
  var config = {
    apiKey: "*****",
    authDomain: "*******",
    databaseURL: "******",
    storageBucket: "********",
    messagingSenderId: "******"
  };
  firebase.initializeApp(config);

  // Get a reference to the database service
  var database = firebase.database();

</script>
```

Let me know if you want more information.

**How can I sync database with my app ?**

**How can I initialize my database connection in offline mode and how can I read and write data to firebase realtime database in offline mode ?**

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I'm afraid your choices of technology is completely upside down. Firebase on the web is meant to be used online (with occasional disconnections) as there is no persistence support.

Comment: @vzsg, Are you making point here to use SQLite instead of Firebase?

Comment: You can't use SQLite in the browser. PouchDB might be a nice alternative though.

Comment: It is about using SQLite with phonegap. I will look into PouchDB..

Comment: @vzsg Actually i want to integrate this with phone gap app (Android Platform) not exactly in browser.

Comment: Does not actually matter. The Firebase Web SDK is not the tool you are looking for here.

Comment: @vzsg What would be the better preference in between `PouchDB` or `SQLite` ? Your suggestions will be great on this.

Comment: I think that's a too broad question even for StackOverflow, and especially for the comments here. PouchDB has a document DB interface, and SQLite is relational. You have to choose whichever fits better to your requirements.